# Is there a way to force the camera orientation to stay in portrait?

Tags: camera, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, device-orientation

My app's orientation is set to portrait mode in tiapp.xml and the the window's orientation mode is also set to portrait. But when I open the camera, the orientation is not locked to portrait, it still rotates. Is there a way to lock this because I need to capture the photos only in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

In the [CameraOptionsType](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/CameraOptionsType) dictionary you pass as options to Ti.Media.showCamera you can set the **autorotate** boolean property: *false* locks the camera preview rotation.

Comment: Thanks @patrick But I already set the autorotate property to false for the camera preview. But what I want to lock the rotation is for the camera screen, not the camera preview. I can't see any way how to do this.